# TravelItineraryReadRQ version

Tags: sabre

Sabre Support.

I am confused about the version I can use in production SOAP API

In this page, it says current production version is 3.5.0
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Get_Itinerary/resources

But when I test production soap api according version 3.5.0 schema, it gives me time out.

Then I copy and modify the request according to your SOAPUI project sample,
which is version 2.0.0, it works.

Does it related to the CPAId I got from my boss?

### Request Samples:

soap body as version 3.5.0. it gives me time out with or without xmlns in TravelItineraryReadRQ element.

```
<TravelItineraryReadRQ Version="3.5.0"
      xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MessagingDetails></MessagingDetails>
    <UniqueID ID="AAAAAA"/>
    <ReturnOptions UnmaskCreditCard="false"/>
</TravelItineraryReadRQ>
```

---

soap body version 2.0.0.0. This works perfectly.

```
      <TravelItineraryReadRQ Version="2.0.0" 
xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <MessagingDetails>
            <Transaction Code="PNR"/>
         </MessagingDetails>
<UniqueID ID="AAAAAA"/>
         </TravelItineraryReadRQ>
```

---

Cheers
Mark Lin.

TravelItineraryReadRQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you are using TravelItineraryReadLLSRQ as an ActionCode?

If so, please try with TravelItineraryReadRQ and let me know if that does it.